# Dynamic product group rules don't work for inherited variant fields

Tags: inheritance, field, shopware6, group, storefront

I've setup the following rule in a dynamic product group:
[image]

Both the parent product and it's variants can be found using the "preview" button, but only the parent product is recognised being in the dynamic product group on the Storefront. Things like promotions using the dynamic product group above don't work. They do work when I stop inheriting the name in those variants and simply copy paste the parents name. Any idea how I'm able to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

By default all variants are being grouped into a single product listing entry in the storefront. I assume this is what you mean when you say that only the parent product is shown. In the preview all variants are always being listed separately for the sake of clarity. You can change the storefront representation of a product by editing a product in the administration:

- choose the "Variants" tab
- click "Storefront representation"
- in the opening modal choose "Product listing"
- select "Expand property values in product listings" and select all the property groups you want to list separately

Comment: Interesting tip, but I'm afraid it isn't what I'm looking for. I mean the fact that the preview window shows which products will get the current `stream` (dynamic product group), yet when adding the association `streams` to all products it only shows the aforementioned stream on the parent product and not its variants. I assume this happens because adding the `streams` association doesn't seem to receive the `streams` that have rules related to inherited product attributes.

Comment: That circumstance is not related to the behavior you described though. The `streams` association isn't being used for selecting the products of a stream. The actual filters you define within a stream are used on runtime 
 for selecting products in the storefront. The mapping entity `product_stream_mapping` of the `streams` association is merely used for cache invalidation. If for some reason you need to fetch the `product_stream` entities related to a variant, use the field `streamIds` to retrieve the ids of related streams. That field will be inherited.